# Microsoft.Data.Edm building multiple languages

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

I have an MVC 4 project using entity framework.  When the project builds it includes a version of each dll for all of the various languages supported (de, es, fr, it, ja, etc...).  I am wondering if this is required?  If not, how do I get the build to only build english (there are no foreseeable plans to go multi-language with this in house app).

I have my assemblies neutral culture set to en-us but that did not change anything.

Thanks.